# set repeated alarm manager for every hour in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to fetch location every hours in android . For that i use alarm manager and set repeated alarm for every hour and just want to write into file after fix time i.e at 8 AM and 12 PM .
I got a problem in setting alarm manager , while i set for every one hour but it execute in 1/2 hour .

```
on button click i start service :

       serviceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AutoMainActivity.this, TrackerService.class);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AutoMainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, ALARM_TRIGGER_AT_TIME,
                    3600000, pendingIntent);

            //3600000 1hrs

            finish();
        }
    });
```

And Service Class are as :

```
Tracker Service.class

String FINAL_STRING;
SharedPreferences pref;
static final int START_TIME = 8;
static final int MID_TIME = 12;

    java.util.Date systemDates = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
    int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(hour == START_TIME)
        {
            edit.putString("smsdata", FINAL_STRING);
            edit.commit();

            //sendSms(START_TAG+pref.getString("smsdata", ""));
            edit.putString("smsdata", "");
            edit.commit();
        }else {

            System.out.println("currentdate:"+simpleDateFormat.toString());
            System.out.println("current_time:"+currentTime);

            Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putString("smsdata", pref.getString("smsdata", "")+FINAL_STRING+"#");
            edit.commit();

            if(hour==MID_TIME)
            {
                //sendSms(START_TAG+pref.getString("smsdata", ""));
                generateNoteOnSD("\n"+START_TAG+pref.getString("smsdata", ""));
                edit.putString("smsdata", "");
                edit.commit();
                System.out.println("mid time");

            }

        }
```

When i execute this the service start on every 30min. but i want on every 60min.

Answer (score 1):

First, you really want to use one of the available constants, like `INTERVAL_HOUR`, with `setInexactRepeating()`.

Second, `setInexactRepeating()` is *inexact*. Android reserves the right to flex the times of the alarms to coalesce events with other scheduled inexact alarms.

So, try switching briefly to `setRepeating()`. If it now works as you expect, your behavior is due to the "inexact" nature of `setInexactRepeating()`.

Also, you can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to examine the scheduled alarms. It may be that you have two alarms scheduled, each going off once per hour.

Comment: i am using alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 20000, 1000 * 60 * 60,receiverIntent); And yet getting unexpected result , i started at 1:29 PM then service start at first at 1:29 PM then 1:48 PM and 2:01 PM????

Comment: @i_max77: Sounds like you have multiple alarms scheduled. Read the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

setInexactRepeating() is the reason why it is not working as you expected. Try following:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstStart, interval, pendingIntent );
```

Comment: still it not working i am using : alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 20000,1000 * 60 * 60,pendingIntent);

Comment: try to use AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: After using RTC_WAKE_UP at 1:29 PM ,i am write date time in file in service class and got this unexpected result : 1.At 1:29 PM 2.then 1:48 PM 3.And 2:01 PM i have set repeated alarm of one hour interval.But it start service firstly at 1:29 then 1:48 ???

Comment: What value has ALARM_TRIGGER_AT_TIME?

Comment: SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 20000

Answer (score 0):

In my application I have the functionality to trigger an alarm in 4 scenarios:

1. Only once for a user-chosen date and time
2. Daily for the chosen time
3. Weekly according to chosen date and time
4. User chosen custom days of the week
   I successfully implement the first 3 scenarios by using the following:

**Only once:**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(date[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.parseInt(date[1])) - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(date[2]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**For daily scheduling:**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

**For weekly scheduling (as per system date):**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        //long interval = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 604800000L;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

**How do I implement weekly alarm scheduling for custom days of the week?**

```
private void scheduleAlarm(int dayOfWeek) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

    // Check we aren't setting it in the past which would trigger it to fire instantly
    if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
    }

    // Set this to whatever you were planning to do at the given time
    PendingIntent yourIntent; 

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, yourIntent);
}

private void setUpAlarms() {

    scheduleAlarm(Calendar.MONDAY);
    scheduleAlarm(Calendar.FRIDAY);
}
```

**Attribution**
Source: https://microeducate.tech/repeating-alarm-for-specific-days-of-week-android/ ,
Question Author : Dhruvil Patel(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367157/dhruvil-patel) , Answer Author : MBH(https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296787/mbh)