# How to run broadcast receiver for every one hour?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

> **I have created broadcast receiver inside Service and this broadcast receiver is running frequently .but i want run this broadcast receiver for every one hour.without disturbing service .any suggestion?**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager =        (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            AppLockApplication.getInstance().getlocationprovider().connect();
            telephonyManager.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            siminfoMap = SimInfo.getSimInfo(telephonyManager,getApplicationContext());
            Log.e(TAG,"-----SIM INFO STATUS------\n");
            for (String keyvalue : siminfoMap.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"SimInfo : "+keyvalue +" : "+siminfoMap.get(keyvalue));
            }
            Intent batteryStatus = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            HealthModel healthModel=new HealthModel();
            healthinfo_Map = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();

            //Bettary status
            int  level= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
            int  plugged= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED,0);
            boolean  present= batteryStatus.getExtras().getBoolean(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PRESENT);
            int  scale= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,-1);
            int  status= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,0);
            String  technology= batteryStatus.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
            int  temperature= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
            int  voltage= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);

            int remaing = -1;
            if (level >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                remaing =scale-level;
            }
            Log.e(TAG,"-----BATTERY STATUS-----\n");
            batteryinfoMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
            batteryinfoMap.put("Plugged",String.valueOf(plugged));
            batteryinfoMap.put("Present",String.valueOf(present));
            batteryinfoMap.put("Battaery Present Percentage", String.valueOf(level));
            batteryinfoMap.put("Battaery Remaining Percentage", String.valueOf(remaing));
            batteryinfoMap.put("Battaery Total Percentage", String.valueOf(scale));
            for (String keyset : batteryinfoMap.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"Battery Info : "+keyset+" : "+batteryinfoMap.get(keyset));
            }

            if(status==1){
                batteryinfoMap.put("Charging Status","Unknown");
            }else if(status==2){
                batteryinfoMap.put("Charging Status","Charging");
            }else if(status==3){
                batteryinfoMap.put("Charging Status","Discharging");
            }else if(status==4){
                batteryinfoMap.put("Charging Status","Not Charging");
            }else if(status==5){
                batteryinfoMap.put("Charging Status","Full");
            }

            batteryinfoMap.put("Temperature",String.valueOf(temperature));
            batteryinfoMap.put("Technology",technology );
            batteryinfoMap.put("Voltage",String.valueOf(voltage));
            connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


            wifiInfo = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            mobileInfo = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


            //Memory status
            memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
            manager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
            memory_info = new HashMap<String,String>();

            memory_info.put(" AvailableMemory",String.valueOf(memoryInfo.availMem ));
            memory_info.put(" LowMemory",String.valueOf(memoryInfo.lowMemory));
            memory_info.put(" threshold",String.valueOf(memoryInfo.threshold));
            memory_info.put(" Totalmemory",String.valueOf(memoryInfo.totalMem));
            Log.e(TAG,"-----RAM  STATUS-----\n");
            for (String keyString : memory_info.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"Memory Info : "+keyString +" :"+memory_info.get(keyString));
            }

            //External memory info :
            extrenal_memory = new HashMap<String,String>();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----EXTERNAL MEMORY STATUS-----\n");
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
                long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSizeLong() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
                long tot=(long)stat.getBlockSizeLong()*(long)stat.getBlockCountLong();
                extrenal_memory.put("Totalsize",String.valueOf(tot));
                extrenal_memory.put("Availablesize",String.valueOf(bytesAvailable));
                for (String keyset : extrenal_memory.keySet()){
                    Log.i(TAG,"External Memory : "+keyset+" : "+extrenal_memory.get(keyset));
                }

            }else {
                Log.i(TAG,"No SD card");
            }

            //Internal memory info :
            internal_memory = new HashMap<String,String>();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----INTERNAL MEMORY STATUS-----\n");
            File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
            long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
            long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
            long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
            long avilablemem=(availableBlocks*blockSize);
            long totalmem=(totalBlocks*blockSize);
            internal_memory.put("Totalsize",String.valueOf(totalmem));
            internal_memory.put("Availablesize",String.valueOf(avilablemem));
            for (String keyset : internal_memory.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"Internal Memory : "+keyset+" : "+internal_memory.get(keyset));
            }

            InfoMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // WIFI status
            if(wifiInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                InfoMap.put("Wifi Type","Mobile Wifi Connection");
            }else if(wifiInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                InfoMap.put("Wifi Type","WIFI data connection");
            }else if(wifiInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX){
                InfoMap.put("Wifi Type"," WiMAX data connection");
            }else if(wifiInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET){
                InfoMap.put("Wifi Type","Ethernet data connection");
            }else if(wifiInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_BLUETOOTH){
                InfoMap.put("Wifi Type","Bluetooth data connection");
            }else {
                InfoMap.put("Wifi Type","Other NewWork");
            }


            InfoMap.put("Wifi-Roaming",String.valueOf(wifiInfo.isRoaming()));
            InfoMap.put("Wifi-SignalInfo",String.valueOf(wifiInfo.isAvailable()));
            InfoMap.put("Wifi-State",String.valueOf(wifiInfo.getState()));

            //Mobile status :
            if(String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getSubtypeName()).equalsIgnoreCase("EDGE")){
                InfoMap.put("MobileType","2G");
            }else if(String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getSubtypeName()).equalsIgnoreCase("HSDPA")||String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getSubtypeName()).equalsIgnoreCase("HSPA")|| String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getSubtypeName()).equalsIgnoreCase("HSPAP")){
                InfoMap.put("MobileType","3G");
            }else if(String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getSubtypeName()).equalsIgnoreCase("LTE")  ){
                InfoMap.put("MobileType","4G");
            }else{
                InfoMap.put("MobileType",String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getSubtypeName()));
            }

            InfoMap.put("Mobile-Roaming",String.valueOf(mobileInfo.isRoaming()));
            InfoMap.put("Mobile-SignalInfo",String.valueOf(mobileInfo.isRoaming()));
            InfoMap.put("Mobile-State",String.valueOf(mobileInfo.getState()));
            Log.e(TAG,"-----CONNECTION STATUS-----\n");
            for (String keyval : InfoMap.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"Connection : "+keyval+" :"+InfoMap.get(keyval));
            }
            Map<String, String> wifiDetails = DisplayWifiState();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----WIFI DETAILS-----\n");
            for (String keywifival : wifiDetails.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"WIFI details : "+keywifival+" : "+wifiDetails.get(keywifival));
            }


            //Installed Apps :
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH);


            Log.e(TAG,"INSTALLED Apps size : "+apps.size());

            installapp_map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----INSTALLED APPS-----\n");
            for (PackageInfo rInfo :apps) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Installed Apps : "+rInfo.packageName+" : "+rInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                installapp_map.put(rInfo.packageName, rInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            }

            runningAppProcessInfo=searchRunningAppProcesses();

            healthModel.setRunningprocessInfo(new JSONObject(runningAppProcessInfo));

            NetInfo netInfo = new NetInfo(context);
            inetaddrinfo = netInfo.getIPAddress();
            if(!(String.valueOf(wifiInfo.getState()).equalsIgnoreCase("connected"))){
            if(inetaddrinfo !=null) {
                for (String keyString : inetaddrinfo.keySet()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Internet : " + keyString + " :" + inetaddrinfo.get(keyString));
                }
            }else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Internet : "+"NO");
            }
            }else
            {
//                for (String keyString : inetaddrinfo.keySet()) {
//                    Log.e(TAG, "Internet : " + keyString + " :" + inetaddrinfo.get(keyString));
//                }
            }

            //Current Apps:
            currnt_task_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> infos = manager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            PackageManager pack=context.getPackageManager();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----CURRENT APP-----\n");
            String currentApp = "NULL";
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 1000*1000, time);
                if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                    }
                    if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                        currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                        String currentAppName="";
                        try {
                            currentAppName = (String) pack.getApplicationLabel(pack.getApplicationInfo(currentApp, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG,"Current App : "+currentApp+" : "+currentAppName);
                        currnt_task_map.put(currentApp,currentAppName);
                    }
                }
            }else {
                for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info :infos) {
                String packageName = info.topActivity.getPackageName();
                String appName="";
                try {
                    appName = (String)     pack.getApplicationLabel(pack.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(TAG,"Current App : "+packageName+" :"+appName );
                currnt_task_map.put(packageName,appName);
            }
            }


            //Recently used apps :
            recent_task_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----RECENT APPS-----\n");
            PackageManager recpack=context.getPackageManager();
            List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = manager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

            String Recentapp = "NULL";
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 1000*1000, time);
                if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);

                        if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                            Recentapp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                            String RecentAppName = "";
                            try {
                                RecentAppName = (String) recpack.getApplicationLabel(recpack.getApplicationInfo(Recentapp, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.i(TAG, "Recent Apps : " + Recentapp + " : " + RecentAppName);
                            recent_task_map.put(Recentapp, RecentAppName);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }else {
                for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo task : recentTasks) {

                Intent baseIntent = task.baseIntent;
                if (baseIntent != null) {
                    String text = baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
                    String appName = "";
                    try {
                        appName = (String) pack.getApplicationLabel(pack.getApplicationInfo(text, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Recent Apps : " + text + " :" + appName);
                    recent_task_map.put(text,(String) appName);
                }else {
                    Log.i(TAG,"RecentTask :"+" No Recent task");
                }
            }
            }

            //Location info :
            location_info = new HashMap<String,String>();

            double Latitude=AppLockApplication.getInstance().getlocationprovider().getLocation().getLatitude();
            double Longitude=AppLockApplication.getInstance().getlocationprovider().getLocation().getLongitude();
            Log.e(TAG,"-----LOCATION-----");
            location_info.put("Latitude",String.valueOf(Latitude));
            location_info.put("Longitude",String.valueOf(Longitude));
            for (String keyset : location_info.keySet()){
                Log.i(TAG,"Location info : "+keyset+" : "+location_info.get(keyset));
            }


            if(siminfoMap !=null){
                healthModel.setSiminfo(new JSONObject(siminfoMap));
            }
            healthModel.setWifideatils(new JSONObject(wifiDetails));
            healthModel.setConectivityInfo(new JSONObject(InfoMap));
            healthModel.setBatteryInfo(new JSONObject(batteryinfoMap));
            healthModel.setMemoreyInfo(new JSONObject(memory_info));
            healthModel.setInstallAppInfo(new JSONObject(installapp_map));
            healthModel.setLocationinfo(new JSONObject(location_info));

                healthModel.setInternalmemory(new JSONObject(internal_memory));

        if (extrenal_memory !=null) {
            healthModel.setExternalmemoryinfo(new JSONObject(extrenal_memory));
        }
            if(inetaddrinfo !=null){
                healthModel.setinetaddress(new JSONObject(inetaddrinfo));
            }
            healthModel.setCurTaskInfo(new JSONObject(currnt_task_map));
            healthModel.setRecentTaskInfo(new JSONObject(recent_task_map));
            if(siminfoMap !=null){
                healthinfo_Map.put("SIMINFORMATION",healthModel.getSiminfo());
            }
            healthinfo_Map.put("BATTERYINFO", healthModel.getBatteryInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("WIFIDETAILS", healthModel.getConectivityInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("WIFIINFO", healthModel.getWifideatils());
            healthinfo_Map.put("MEMORYINFO", healthModel.getMemoreyInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("INSTALLAPPINFO",healthModel.getInstallAppInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("RUNNINGAPPINFO", healthModel.getRunningprocessInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("CURRTASKINFO", healthModel.getCurTaskInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("RECENTTASKINFO", healthModel.getRecentTaskInfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("INETADDRESS", healthModel.getinetaddress());
            healthinfo_Map.put("LOCATION",healthModel.getLocationinfo());
            healthinfo_Map.put("INTERNALMEMORY",healthModel.getInternalmemory());
            healthinfo_Map.put("EXTERNALMEMORY",healthModel.getExternalmemoryinfo());
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(healthinfo_Map);
            healthinfo_Map=null;
            healthModel=null;
            siminfoMap=null;
            wifiDetails=null;
            InfoMap=null;
            batteryinfoMap=null;
            memory_info=null;
            installapp_map=null;
            location_info=null;
            internal_memory=null;
            extrenal_memory=null;
            inetaddrinfo=null;
            currnt_task_map=null;
            recent_task_map=null;
            jsonObject=null;
            runningAppProcessInfo=null;

        }

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AlarmManager which runs ever 1 hour to start broadcast reciever

```
public int setAlarm() {
    Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, mBatInfoReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                    0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    long wkupTime = Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis() + 36000; 

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wkupTime ,3600000, pendingIntent);

    return 0;
}
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16460824/4247543)

Comment: will you please elabrate?

Comment: this broadcast receiver is inside service

Comment: where i need to put this setAlaram() method?

Comment: Try it inside ur service

Answer (score 2):

Use AlarmManager for this purpose
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1):

> You can use handler for setting time to call receiver inside of
>   service. Try the following code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override 
            public void run() {
                //you can call your broadcast receiver here
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(hourlyTask, 01, 1000 * 1 * 60 * 60);
```