# How do I execute some code after one hour in background?

Tags: java, android

I am using a background service to play an audio whenever the user selects a button. But what I would like to do is play the audio every 60 minutes. How would I go about doing this?

I have already tried using a handler and setting the timer to 60 minute then executing  the line of code that plays the audio but it just plays the audio automatically whenever the use selects the button.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Boolean state = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //i would like to play this audio every 60minute in the background
        player = MediaPlayer.create(BackgroundService.this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);

        //this will make the ringtone continuously playing
        player.setLooping(true);

        //staring the player
        player.start();

        return  START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //stopping the player when service is destroyed
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details like how you are currently using the service to understand the situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set repeated alarm manager for every hour in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460612/set-repeated-alarm-manager-for-every-hour-in-android)

Comment: Have you checked the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460612/set-repeated-alarm-manager-for-every-hour-in-android

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with `BroadcastReceiver`

Set `AlarmManager` with your time interval

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Your Broadcast Receiver");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time_interval, pendingIntent);
```

Specify your `BroadcastReceiver` in `Manifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.YourReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="Your Broadcast Receiver" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to loop your handler

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 


int count = 0;
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 

        // do the task here
        Log.d(TAG, "runn test");


        if (count++ < 5)
            //will continue to loop 5 times
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

    } 
}; 
// trigger first time 
handler.post(runnable);
```